# How to query a many to many entity list via Specification API in Spring Data JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 entities with Many-To-Many relationships

```
   public class Enterprise{
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 50)
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "jpa-uuid")
        private String id;
        
        fields...
      
        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "enterprise_to_tag",
                   joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "enterprise"), 
                   inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag"))
        private Set<EnterpriseTag> tags;
    }
```

and

```
public class EnterpriseTag{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "jpa-uuid")
    private String id;
    
    fields...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Enterprise> enterprises;      
}
```

I want to query enterprise list by some tags' ID then pack them to Page

```
private Page<Enterprise> searchEnterprise(int number, int size, String keyword, String tags, String county)
            throws BusinessException {
        validPageNumberAndPageSize(number, size);
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(number, size);
        Specification<Enterprise> specification = (Specification<Enterprise>) (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(keyword)) {
                Predicate predicateName = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%");
                Predicate predicateSerialNumber = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("serialNumber"), "%" + keyword + "%");
               
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.or(predicateName, predicateSerialNumber, predicateOrganizationCode)));
            }
            return criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])).getRestriction();
        };
        //filter by tags here
        if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(tags)) {
            List<String> tagIds = Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(tags, ','));
            List<Enterprise> enterprises = enterpriseRepository.findAll(specification).stream().filter(enterprise ->
                    enterprise.getTags().stream().map(EnterpriseTag::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()).containsAll(tagIds))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new PageImpl<>(enterprises, pageable, enterprises.size());
        } else {
            return enterpriseRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to write this query. I have to handle it base on a database query result. But it's risky. If too much data is queried from the database, it will take up a lot of memory. Please help me to write this query by Specification API. Thanks.